# Can't connect to my docker services in docker when using my vpn

Tags: firewall, docker, ufw

Im trying to setup all my docker services so they will only be accesible when using my vpn, but it isnt working.

Those are my ufw rules

```
22/tcp                     ALLOW       192.168.1.0/24
51820/udp                  ALLOW       Anywhere
9443                       ALLOW       192.168.1.0/24
51820/udp (v6)             ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

ssh only from my local network

51820 is my vpn

and I want to acces 9443 only from my local network or vpn.

I can access it in my local network, but I cant load the web when using the vpn. How comes? if when using vpn im having the same network.

Answer (score 0):

fixed with

```
 ufw allow in on docker0
```